# Into the Deep Dreaming!

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming, changeling-20th-anniversary

The Deep Dreaming <sup>1</sup> is a place that amps up a Kithain's birthright to 11. They become the most powerful and dreaming version of themselves.

For example, even the ugliest Sidhe is actually quite handsome in the Autumn World (Base Appearance 3) and becomes so beautiful that it hurts to look at them (Appearance 7) in Deep Dreaming). The most stunning of them that look like this in the Autumn World (Base Appearance 7) and become so beautiful that they'd stun Aphrodite (Appearance 11) in Deep Dreaming. But Sidhe actually are somewhat easy, because their Birthrights are on the more straightforward side <sup>2</sup>.

On the other hand, there are cases like Selkies that are much harder <sup>3</sup>, as they seem... rather situational. Still, at least Grace of the Sea seems to be manageable: add one type of roll that can't be botched in Far Dreaming and two in Deep Dreaming, reduce difficulties by 5 for any Dex roll in the water in Far and automatically succeed in Deep Dreaming.

And then there's Redcaps <sup>4</sup>. They outright don't seem to have a Birthright that *could* be modified under the rules <sup>1</sup>? The Dark Appetite already only needs Glamour for the most heinous materials, and Bully Browbeat... eh... adds maybe two items that can't be botched to the list of unbotchable skills?

You see, it gets complicated easily...

**Is there a complementary list of how to handle Far/Deep Dreaming Birthrights and how to modify them for the *standard* Kithain beyond the rather rough guidelines in the core book that eludes me?**

---

1 - C20 p.301
2 - C20 p.107
3 - C20 p.105
4 - C20 p.103

Answer (score 1):

### The Augmen, from *Dreams and Nightmares* for second edition

As far as I can tell the only source for Deep Dreaming modifications to Birthrights and Frailties is *[Dreams & Nightmares](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/2173/Dreams-and-Nightmares)* for the second edition.

In Chapter Three: The Deep Dreaming, there's a section titled "The Augmen Revisited". The Augmen is the name given by Changelings to the change which comes upon them as they move into the Far Dreaming, and then again into the Deep Dreaming. This section - and the matching "The Augmen" section in Chapter Two - details the increased effects of Birthrights and Frailties for each of the main kith from the second edition corebook: Boggans, Eshu, Nockers, Pooka, Redcaps, Satyrs, Sidhe, Sluagh and Trolls.

Many of these translate directly into C20 - for example, Boggans Craftwork birthright allows them to work even faster when unobserved, and faster than mortals even if observed, so it would work the same in C20 as in second edition. Others need a little parsing or extra work, but should provide enough info to get you going - and inspiration for how to adjust other C20 kiths accordingly.