# Fighting off the Nightmare

Tags: world-of-darkness, changeling-the-dreaming, changeling-20th-anniversary

It happened. In our latest venture, we were in the [Deep Dreaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/201238/into-the-deep-dreaming) and had to Unleash our Arts.<sup>1</sup> Obviously, this incurred a few points of Nightmare.<sup>2</sup>

Now, those points are burning like evil eyes in the darkness on my character sheet and I need to know if I can get rid of them in a way that is not invoking imbalance! Sure, I still got a lot of 'air', but accumulating Nightmare leads to Bedlam, and Bedlam is BAD! I'd rather try to cure the Nightmare now than thread the dangerous path to Bedlam.<sup>3</sup>

What mechanics can get rid of Nightmare?

---

1 - C20 p.196
2 - C20 p.274-275
3 - C20 p.294

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really hard. So far I found:

### House Liam

If you meet someone from House Liam and can make him lay hands upon you, they can - for the price of a Glamour - remove a point of Nightmare with their birthright.<sup>1</sup>

---

1 - C20 p.134